# PostgreSQL 9.3 executeBatch command

Tags: postgresql, jdbc

I am adding the following commands to batch and execute it by invoking `executeBatch()` JDBC function.

```
insert into blabla (id,value) values ('1','666666')
insert into blabla (id,value) values ('1','8888')
```

`id` is unique.

I expect that the first sql command will work and be committed to DB.

The API of the `executeBatch()` command indicates that when `BatchUpdateException` exception is thrown, all the previous SQL that succeed will be committed to the DB.

Actual result is that no sql command is committed to the DB. Why?

I'm using the following syntax:

```
int[] res = null;
try {
     conn.setAutoCommit(false);
     Statement batch_stmt = conn.createStatement();
     for (String sql: sqlList) {
          batch_stmt.addBatch(sql);
     }
     res = batch_stmt.executeBatch();

     conn.commit();
     batch_stmt.clearBatch();
     batch_stmt.close();
} catch (BatchUpdateException e) {
         int[] err_res = e.getUpdateCounts();   
         try {
           conn.commit();
         } catch (SQLException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
         }
} catch (SQLException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Also I tried auto commit true and I got the same results.

```
int[] res = null;

try {
     Statement batch_stmt = conn.createStatement();
     for (String sql: sqlList) {
          batch_stmt.addBatch(sql);
     }

     res = batch_stmt.executeBatch();
     batch_stmt.clearBatch();
     batch_stmt.close();
} catch (BatchUpdateException e) {
         int[] err_res = e.getUpdateCounts();   
} catch (SQLException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
}
```

By the way, `e.getUpdateCounts();` returned that first sql did succeed.

Comment: In Postgres you can't commit parts of a transaction. You either commit or rollback everything. Where did you read that you can partially commit a transaction through `executeBatch()`. [The JavDocs are pretty clear](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeBatch%28%29): "*However, the driver's behavior must be consistent with a particular DBMS, either always continuing to process commands or never continuing to process commands*"

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I guess he is misinterpreting the sentence _"The possible implementations and return values have been modified in the Java 2 SDK, Standard Edition, version 1.3 to accommodate the option of continuing to process commands in a batch update after a BatchUpdateException object has been thrown."_

Comment: You are talking about the remaining sql commands:                              If one of the commands in a batch update fails to execute properly, this method throws a BatchUpdateException, and a JDBC driver may or may not continue to process the remaining commands in the batch. However, the driver's behavior must be consistent with a particular DBMS, either always continuing to process commands or never continuing to process commands.                                       I'm talking about the previous commands before the problematic one that caused the exception. i expect them to succeed.

Answer (score 1):

> I expect that the first sql command will work and be committed to DB.

A batch may be run in autocommit mode.

If autocommit is on, then the first statement should succeed and be committed, then the second should fail with an error. Checking the results of the batch should confirm this, and you should be able to see the new value.

If autocommit is off, then the first statement begins a new transaction if one is not already open. The second fails and aborts the transaction. So neither statement has any effect.

See [`executeBatch` in `AbstractJDBCStatement.java`](https://github.com/pgjdbc/pgjdbc/blob/master/org/postgresql/jdbc2/AbstractJdbc2Statement.java#L2893).

You say that you tried with autocommit on, but it's not clear that's the case. Add an explicit `conn.setAutoCommit(true);` .

If you find that the statement still fails to take effect in autocommit mode, please supply a complete and compileable + executable `.java` file with associated `.sql` setup script as an attachment to a GitHub issue on https://github.com/pgjdbc/pgjdbc that, when run using its `main` method, demonstrates your problem. Then comment here with a link to the issue you filed. Also include your server side logs from a test run with `log_statement = on` set.